# PowerBI - TIME function limitation problem

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have column with number of seconds and I'm trying to convert it to `HH:mm:ss` format.
All is working well if values are not empty or above 32767 since this is [limitation of TIME function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457).

My question is: how can I still convert values above 32767 in `HH:mm:ss` format?

What I have so far is:

```
time_elapsed = IF(ISBLANK([time_in_sec]);"NaN";FORMAT(TIME(0;0;[time_in_sec]);"HH:mm:ss"))
```

But this not even checking because I don't know how to pass empty field as empty field and not Null or "Nan" or anything else when dealing with integer column.

For all other cases function `FORMAT(TIME(0;0;[time_in_sec]);"HH:mm:ss")` works well.

So 2 problems - how to convert numbers larger than 32767 to `HH:mm:ss` and how to just pass empty fields. 
And in case of negative integer number it should return empty field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FORMAT( DIVIDE( [DurationInSeconds] ) , 86400), "HH:mm:ss" )
```

This one-liner returns time part. It trims the day part if the DurationInSeconds is larger than 1 day (86400 seconds). If Duration is blank it returns blank.

Answer (score 3):

1) It's possible that space character or another unprintable character may be present. In this case the value isn't considered BLANK. We need to see a sample of your data to tell exactly what's going on.

2) You can implement the formula, that converts seconds to the HH:MI:SS format, yourself, as follows:

```
  // calculated column
  hh_mi_ss = 
    VAR hr = FLOOR( query[column] / 3600, 1 )                   // hours
    VAR mn = FLOOR( MOD( query[column], 3600) / 60, 1)          // minutes
    VAR ss = FLOOR( MOD ( MOD( query[column], 3600) , 60 ), 1)  // seconds
RETURN FORMAT( TIME(hr, mn,ss), "HH:mm:ss" )
```

[image]

Comment: I still have "An argument of function 'TIME' has the wrong data type or the result is too large or too small." I see now that I have some negative values in original data...I'll have to modify my post. But besides negative values which are also integers I don't have any other types of data appearing.

Comment: I'll try adding some IF in combination with your answer and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer from [@Nick Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58097298/2119941) resolved my problem, I only needed to add IF function to regulate appearance of negative numbers, zeros and empty cells.
So I used:

```
hh_mi_ss = if([time_column]>0,(
 VAR hr = FLOOR( [time_column] / 3600, 1)                   // hours
 VAR mn = FLOOR( MOD( [time_column]; 3600) / 60, 1)          // minutes
 VAR ss = FLOOR( MOD ( MOD( [time_column], 3600) ,60 ), 1)  // seconds
RETURN FORMAT( TIME(hr, mn,ss), "HH:mm:ss" ));
"Empty, 0 or negative value")
```

And in my locale I had to replace `,` with `;` in argument of function.

Comment: Your code is a total mess. Your logic might be represented as: `IF (time>0, AcceptedAnswerResult, "Empty") `